# Why can't I return a Set from page.$$eval in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

This code works as expected, and I see an array of links in my  console:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })

const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto("https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/")

let result = await page.$$eval("body a", (data) => {
  let links = data.map((elem) => elem.href)
  return links
})

console.log(result)
```

Now, when I try returning a set, I get an empty object:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })

const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto("https://www.scrapethissite.com/pages/")

let result = await page.$$eval("body a", (data) => {
  let links = data.map((elem) => elem.href)
  return new Set(links) // <---
})

console.log(result) // here I get {}
```

Can someone explain why it is happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that you'll be transferring the result of that `pageFunction` between two execution contexts. Therefore, `$$eval` has to serialize (`JSON.stringify`) the result.

From [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

> Only enumerable own properties are visited. This means Map, Set, etc.
> will become "{}".